# Unable to track record by record processing in LSTM algorithm for text classification?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, word2vec

We are working on multi-class text classification and following is the process which we have used.

1) We have created 300 dim's vector with word2vec word embedding using our own data and then passed that vector as a weights to LSTM embedding layer.

2) And then we have used one LSTM layer and one dense layer.

Here below is my code:

```
input_layer = layers.Input((train_seq_x.shape[1], ))

embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(len(word_index)+1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input_layer)
embedding_layer = layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(embedding_layer)

lstm_layer1 = layers.LSTM(300,return_sequences=True,activation="relu")(embedding_layer)
lstm_layer1 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(lstm_layer1)

flat_layer = layers.Flatten()(lstm_layer1)

output_layer = layers.Dense(33, activation="sigmoid")(flat_layer)

model = models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Please help me out on the below questions:

Q1) Why did we pass word embedding vector(300 dim's) as weights in LSTM embedding layer?

Q2) How can we know optimal number of neural in LSTM layer?

Q3) Can you please explain how the single record processing in LSTM algorithm?

Please let me know if you requires more information on the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1) Why did we pass word embedding vector(300 dim's) as weights in
>   LSTM embedding layer?

In a very simplistic way, you can think of an embedding layers as a lookup table which converts a word (represented by its index in a dictionary) to a vector. It is a trainable layers. Since you have already trained word embeddings instead of initializing the embedding layer with the random weight you initialize it with the vectors you have learned.

```
Embedding(len(word_index)+1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input_layer)
```

So here you are

- creating an embedding layer or a look up table which can lookup words
  indices 0 to  len(word_index).
- Each lookuped up word will map to a vector of size 300.
- This lookup table is loaded with the vectors from "embedding_matrix"
  (which is a pretrained model).
- trainable=False will freez the weight in this layer.

You have passed 300 because it is the vector size of your pretrained model (embedding_matrix)

> Q2) How can we know optimal number of neural in LSTM layer?

You have created a LSTM layer with takes 300 size vector as input and returns a vector of size 300. The output size and number of stacked LSTMS are hyperparameters which is tuned manually (usually using KFold CV)

> Q3) Can you please explain how the single record processing in LSTM
>   algorithm?

- A single record/sentence(s) are converted into indices of the vocabulary. So for every sentence you have an array of indices.
- A batch of these sentences are created and feed as input to the model.
- LSTM is unwrapped by passing in one index at a time as input at each timestep.
- Finally the ouput of the LSTM is forward propagated by a final dense
  layer to size 33. So looks like each input is mapped to one of 33
  classes in your case.

### Simple example

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten, LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from nltk.lm import Vocabulary
from keras.utils import to_categorical
training_data = [ "it was a good movie".split(), "it was a bad movie".split()]
training_target = [1, 0]
v = Vocabulary([word for s in training_data for word in s])
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(v),50,input_length = 5, dropout = 0.2))
model.add(LSTM(10, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
x = np.array([list(map(lambda x: v[x], s)) for s in training_data])
y = to_categorical(training_target)
model.fit(x,y)
```

---

Comment: Thanks for response. It's really helpful.

Comment: Can you please elaborate Q1. and Consider if pretrained word embedding is not present then how can we initialize weights?

Comment: Create an embedding layer with embeddings_initializer='uniform' (which will initialise weight from uniform distribution) and most importantly set trainable=True (this will backpropagate the loss through the embedding layer adjusting/training the weights)

Comment: Thanks. And model.add(LSTM(10)) vs model.add(LSTM(1))?. Here I knew output shape will be (None, 10) or (None, 1). but what will happens internally?